# Не получается возобновить screen

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, gnu-screen

```
$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
        595.tty1.             (08/16/2021 08:53:16 PM)      (Attached)
1 Socket in /run/screen/S-root.
$ screen -r
There is a screen on:
        595.tty1.             (08/16/2021 08:53:16 PM)      (Attached)
There is no screen to be resumed.
```

У меня работает окно screen, скрипт в окне тоже работает (приходят уведомления в телеге), но возобновить его не могу в чём может быть проблема ?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 3):

один экземпляр программы *screen* у вас запущен, и подключен (состояние `attached`) к терминалу.

если бы он не был подключен (было бы состояние `detached`), то командой

```
$ screen -r
```

можно было бы его подключить к вашему текущему терминалу.

а так как он уже подключен, надо предварительно его **отключить**, добавив опцию `-d`:

```
$ screen -r -d
```

или короче:

```
$ screen -rd
```